# Python 3 ASCII code 219 issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I compared code to other training example code out there and did a compare and everything matches. Here is my issue: I have a health bar and when I take damage the bar decreases.

The problem is when in my code I use █ the pipe line after the bar never stays put, it always move dynamically. When I use / the pipe bar always stays put and no issue. I'm guessing there is something in my terminal tool (using Pycharm) that it doesn't like ascii code 219. If it matters from reading forums the tool is set to UTF-8. example below so might not format correctly but top part you can see the | being shifted when using █ and the bottom part is fine when using /.

[image]

```
                   ______________________________           __________ 
CARLOS:    2210/3260 |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■        |   132/132 |//////////|    

                      __________________                  __________ 
CARLOS:    2219/3260 |///////////////// |        132/132 |//////////|
```

Code:

```
def get_stats(self):
    hp_bar = ""
    bar_ticks = (self.hp / self.maxhp) * 100 / 4

    mp_bar = ""
    mp_ticks = (self.mp / self.maxmp) * 100 / 10

    while bar_ticks > 0:
        hp_bar += '█'
        bar_ticks -= 1

    #num_spaces_needed = (100/4) - len(hp_bar)
    #str_spaces_needed = ""
    #while num_spaces_needed > 0:
        #str_spaces_needed += " "
        #num_spaces_needed -= 1

    while len(hp_bar) < 25:
        hp_bar += " "

    while mp_ticks > 0:
        mp_bar += "/"
        mp_ticks -= 1

    while len(mp_bar) < 10:
        mp_bar += " "

    hp_string = str(self.hp) + "/" + str(self.maxhp)
    current_hp = ""

    if len(hp_string) < 9:
        decreased = 9 - len(hp_string)

        while decreased > 0:
            current_hp += " "
            decreased -= 1

        current_hp += hp_string
    else:
        current_hp = hp_string

    mp_string = str(self.mp) + "/" + str(self.maxmp)
    current_mp = ""

    if len(mp_string) < 7:
        decreased = 7 - len(mp_string)
        while decreased > 0:
            current_mp += " "
            decreased -= 1

        current_mp += mp_string

    else:
        current_mp = mp_string

    print("                      _______________________________              __________ ")
    print(bcolors.BOLD + self.name + "    " +
          current_hp + " |" + bcolors.BAR + hp_bar + bcolors.ENDC + "|    " +
          current_mp + " |" + bcolors.OKBLUE + mp_bar + bcolors.ENDC + "|    ")
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of the actual code.

Comment: *ascii* 219??? What do you mean?

Comment: **don't attach images to code, always post code as formatted text, btw**

Comment: the format of my example Carlos didn't turn out well. hopefully the example code will be more helpful. using ascii code 219 in hp_bar += ' █' it shifts the pipe in my second to last line of code. replacing it with hp_bar += "/" no problem and no shifting occurs. please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I've had the same issue with this and other characters in Pycharm, which by default seems to use a font with some of these extended ascii characters being wider. You can choose a different font in the settings.

Comment: the setting did make █ thinner but the     |    132/132 |//////////|      still get shifted to the left.

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if they're using the Windows console, that character would be `b'\xdb'.decode('cp850')` or `'\u2588'`.

Comment: finally figured out how to post image, should be link on first part of paragraph, something is broken with chrome had to use MS Edge

Comment: Sorry if this post is "messy", im new to all this and still learning. idea is 2210/3260 is my health and the █ will dynamiclly change when i get hit or heal. when the █ decreases everything after the last | of my health get shifted to the left, it like its taking up the subtracted █ space. in the code if i change the character to be / then no shifted occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your font type

1. Navigate to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Font
2. Font: Source Code Pro
3. Apply -> Ok
4. Rerun the program

Answer (score -1):

Try the following at the top of your script:

```
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```